# Keep automatically searching for connection snap7

Tags: python, tcp, raspberry-pi

We want to autoconnect with the PLC through wifi. When the raspberry is starting up and runs his program automatically. It should be a stand alone raspberry so we don't have a keyboard or anything. We send the data via snap7.
This works, but if the wifi is disconnecting I get this error: "ISO: An error occurred during recv TCP: Connection timed out"
Sometimes in the beginning of the program we get this error: "Snap7Exception:  TCP : Unreachable peer"

My program stops but we should have something so our wifi is reconnected again without stopping the program. I guess we need something to catch our error and use this in a program with a try or something.

My program at this moment:

```
import snap7
import struct
import time
from snap7.snap7exceptions import Snap7Exception
import re
from ctypes import c_int, c_char_p, byref, sizeof, c_uint16, c_int32, c_byte
from ctypes import c_void_p

client = snap7.client.Client()

db_number = 109

print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

while True:

    if client.get_connected() == False: 
        client.connect('192.168.5.2', 0, 1) #('IP-address', rack, slot)
        print('not connected')
        time.sleep(0.2)
    else:
        print('connected')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you can catch errors with the [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) statement.

You can try something along this line:

```
while True:

    if client.get_connected() == False:
        try:
            client.connect('192.168.5.2', 0, 1) #('IP-address', rack, slot)
            print('not connected')
            time.sleep(0.2)
        except Snap7Exception as e:
            continue
    else:
        print('connected')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **`try-exception`** for connecting and reading the PLC, such as below code:

```
from time import sleep
from snap7 import client as s7


def plc_connect(ip, rack, slot, stop_tries, freq):
    plc = s7.Client()
    tries = 1
    while tries < stop_tries and not plc.get_connected():
        try:
            print('trying for connecting to PLC ...')
            sleep(freq)
            plc.connect(ip, rack, slot)
            return True

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("warning in PLC connection >>{}".format(e))
            sleep(freq)

            if tries == (stop_tries - 1):
                print('error in plc connection')
                return False

        tries += 1
    return False


def data_reader():
    plc = s7.Client()
    try:
        result, data_items = plc.read_multi_vars(data_items)
        return result, data_items
    except Exception as e:
        print('warning:>>{}'.format(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

import snap7
from snap7.exceptions import Snap7Exception

# client = snap7.client.Client()
connect = False


def dataPLC(client_):
    print(client_.db_read(100, 10, 4))
    time.sleep(2)


while True:

    if not connect:
        try:
            client = snap7.client.Client()
            client.connect('172.20.255.200', 0, 2)
            time.sleep(1)
            connect = client.get_connected()
            print('plc connect ', connect)
        except Snap7Exception as e:
            connect = False
            continue
    else:
        try:
            if connect:
                print('connection')
                dataPLC(client)

        except Snap7Exception as e:
            client.destroy()
            print('error ', e)
            connect = False
            continue
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.